# Postgres query using filter and counts grouped by month

Tags: postgresql, group-by

Below is the data table -

```
 del_no  |   Pkt   | direction  |  Env  | start_datetimestamp |
---------+---------+------------+-------+---------------------+
 H_00002 |  02     |  SOUTH     | PROD  | 2022-10-29 16:20:57 |
 E20     |  20     |  NORTH     | PROD  | 2022-10-30 16:41:37 |
 H_00002 |  02     |  NORTH     | TEST  | 2022-10-30 17:21:17 |
 E20     |  20     |  SOUTH     | DEV   | 2022-10-30 17:30:24 |
 H_00004 |  02     |  NORTH     | PROD  | 2022-10-30 16:52:48 |
 H_00004 |  02     |  SOUTH     | PROD  | 2022-10-30 19:03:36 |
 H_00007 |  02     |  NORTH     | PROD  | 2022-10-30 20:52:48 |
 H_00007 |  02     |  SOUTH     | PROD  | 2022-10-30 21:03:36 |
 H_00015 |  02     |  SOUTH     | TEST  | 2022-11-13 19:11:10 |
 L 0013  |  13     |  NORTH     | PROD  | 2022-11-14 20:06:46 |
 H_00015 |  02     |  NORTH     | TEST  | 2022-11-15 20:17:40 |
 L0021   |  21     |  SOUTH     | TEST  | 2022-11-15 20:56:18 |
 H_00015 |  02     |  NORTH     | PROD  | 2022-11-15 20:17:40 |
 L0027   |  21     |  SOUTH     | DEV   | 2022-11-30 20:56:18 |
 H_00019 |  02     |  NORTH     | PROD  | 2022-11-30 20:17:40 |
 L0023   |  21     |  SOUTH     | TEST  | 2022-11-30 20:56:18 |
 H_00019 |  02     |  SOUTH     | TEST  | 2022-11-30 20:17:40 |
 L0025   |  21     |  SOUTH     | TEST  | 2022-11-30 20:56:18 |
 H_00019 |  02     |  SOUTH     | DEV   | 2022-11-30 20:17:40 |
```

I want to count the number of rounds with below conditions -

1- Filter by Pkt where Pkt = 02 only.
2- Group by 'del_no' (consider NORTH and SOUTH one complete round), then counts all the rounds by monthly.
3- Segregate the counts based on Env. (e.g. 1st and 3rd row is one complete round and both has PROD and TEST env so that one count should be in PROD/TEST Env, same goes for other)

Output -

```
Month   |       Env     | Counts |
--------+---------------+--------+
 Oct    | PROD/TEST     |  1     |
 Oct    | PROD          |  2     |
 Nov    | PROD/TEST     |  1     |
 Nov    | PROD/TEST/DEV |  1     |
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/FGIzl6hy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select "Month", sum(rounds)"Counts", "Env" from
(   select del_no,
           to_char(start_datetimestamp,'Mon') "Month",
           least( count(*)filter(where direction='SOUTH')
                 ,count(*)filter(where direction='NORTH')) rounds,
           string_agg(distinct env,'/' order by env) "Env"
    from tablename where pkt='2' group by del_no, 2
) group by "Month","Env";
```

| Month | Counts | Env |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nov | 1 | DEV/PROD/TEST |
| Nov | 1 | PROD/TEST |
| Oct | 2 | PROD |
| Oct | 1 | PROD/TEST |

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8QHoZvJ_)

1. By default, `Env` are ordered alphabetically inside the field.
2. Textual abbreviation of `Month` makes it less usable and sorts alphabetically. A [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) would instead mark everything in October with a usable and sortable date of `2022-10-01`, November as `2022-11-01`, which could simplify further processing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's working as expected.

Comment: Hi @Zegarek..sorry for updating the data and output little bit... I have added 2 more rows in data table in which the same del_no (H_00018) starts on Oct but round get completed in Nov. How can we modify the query to get the desired output? it starts on Oct so the count should be in Oct month. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This change is significant enough that it makes more sense to open a new thread. What you now added looks like this question will now become a gaps-and-islands problem, so there will be an additional layer where you have to track openings and closings of rounds. Specify if you want to respect the earliest or latest open in a sequence, earliest or latest close. Also, you'll need to decide which month you assign the finalised round to - the one when it opened or the closing one (updated output suggests the former). Otherwise your yearly counts won't match the sums of monthly counts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have opened another thread - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77443712/postgres-query-total-counts-grouped-by-month-and-year)

Comment: @RKIDEV It looks like someone closed your new thread. Try to research some threads on [`gaps-and-islands`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) tag and give it a shot - there are lots of resources so you might very well solve it yourself. If not, edit the new question adding your attempt and that should be sufficient to satisfy the *minimum input* rule and reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple CTEs, where First cte used to filter out any **del_no** with incomplete round, and second and third used to aggregate data based on month and Environment :

```
with cte as (
  select del_no
  from tableName
  where Pkt = '2'
  group by del_no
  having count(distinct direction) = 2
),
cte2 as (
  select distinct to_char(start_datetimestamp, 'YYYY-MM') as _Month, t.del_no, Env
  from cte c
  inner join tableName t on c.del_no = t.del_no
),
cte3 as (
  select _Month, del_no, string_agg(distinct env, '/') as Env
  from cte2
  group by _Month, del_no
)
select _Month, env, count(env) as Counts 
from cte3
group by _Month, env
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q5xVaQ0W)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's working as expected.

Comment: Hi @SelVazi..sorry for updating the data and output little bit... I have added 2 more rows in data table in which the same del_no (H_00018) starts on Oct but round get completed in Nov. How can we modify the query to get the desired output? it starts on Oct so the count should be in Oct month. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This modification require a different approach, you need to create a follow-up question, I'm sure you will get an answer

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have opened another thread - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77443712/postgres-query-total-counts-grouped-by-month-and-year)