# Postgres query total counts grouped by month and year

Tags: postgresql, group-by

Below is the data table -

```
 del_no  |   Pkt   | direction  |  Env  | start_datetimestamp |
---------+---------+------------+-------+---------------------+
 H_00002 |  02     |  SOUTH     | PROD  | 2022-10-29 16:20:57 |
 E20     |  20     |  NORTH     | PROD  | 2022-10-30 16:41:37 |
 H_00002 |  02     |  NORTH     | TEST  | 2022-10-30 17:21:17 |
 E20     |  20     |  SOUTH     | DEV   | 2022-10-30 17:30:24 |
 H_00004 |  02     |  NORTH     | PROD  | 2022-10-30 16:52:48 |
 H_00004 |  02     |  SOUTH     | PROD  | 2022-10-30 19:03:36 |
 H_00007 |  02     |  NORTH     | PROD  | 2022-10-30 20:52:48 |
 H_00007 |  02     |  SOUTH     | PROD  | 2022-10-30 21:03:36 |
 H_00015 |  02     |  SOUTH     | TEST  | 2022-11-13 19:11:10 |
 L 0013  |  13     |  NORTH     | PROD  | 2022-11-14 20:06:46 |
 H_00015 |  02     |  NORTH     | TEST  | 2022-11-15 20:17:40 |
 L0021   |  21     |  SOUTH     | TEST  | 2022-11-15 20:56:18 |
 H_00015 |  02     |  NORTH     | PROD  | 2022-11-15 20:17:40 |
 L0027   |  21     |  SOUTH     | DEV   | 2022-11-30 20:56:18 |
 H_00019 |  02     |  NORTH     | PROD  | 2022-11-30 20:17:40 |
 L0023   |  21     |  SOUTH     | TEST  | 2022-11-30 20:56:18 |
 H_00019 |  02     |  SOUTH     | TEST  | 2022-11-30 20:17:40 |
 L0025   |  21     |  SOUTH     | TEST  | 2022-11-30 20:56:18 |
 H_00019 |  02     |  SOUTH     | DEV   | 2022-11-30 20:17:40 |
 H_00018 |  02     |  SOUTH     | PROD  | 2023-10-31 20:17:40 |
 H_00018 |  02     |  NORTH     | PROD  | 2023-11-02 03:17:40 |
 H_00033 |  02     |  SOUTH     | PROD  | 2023-10-31 20:17:40 |
 H_00033 |  02     |  NORTH     | DEV   | 2023-11-02 03:17:40 |
```

I want to count the number of rounds with below conditions -

1- Filter by Pkt where Pkt = 02 only.
2- Group by 'del_no' (consider NORTH and SOUTH one complete round), then counts all the rounds by monthly and yearly.
3- Segregate the counts based on Env. (e.g. 1st and 3rd row is one complete round and both has PROD and TEST env so that one count should be in PROD/TEST Env, same goes for other).
4- If same del_no(H_00018) starts on another month and end on next month so the count should be added in start month.

Output -

```
Month   |       Env     | Counts |
--------+---------------+--------+
2022-10 | PROD/TEST     |  1     |
2022-10 | PROD          |  2     |
2022-11 | PROD/TEST     |  1     |
2022-11 | PROD/TEST/DEV |  1     |
2023-10 | PROD          |  1     |
2023-10 | PROD/DEV      |  1     |
```

Below query is not working for 4th condition -

```
select "Month",sum(rounds)"Counts","Env" from (
    select del_no,
           to_char(start_datetimestamp,'YYYY-MM') "Month",
           least( count(*)filter(where direction='SOUTH')
                 ,count(*)filter(where direction='NORTH')) rounds,
           string_agg(distinct env,'/' order by env) "Env"
    from tablename where pkt='2' group by del_no,2)
group by "Month","Env";
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/FGIzl6hy

Comment: Hi! On StackOverflow we provide support, we don't do your job for you. What's your current attempt on tackling this and what is exactly the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple CTEs :

```
with cte as (
  select del_no
  from tableName
  where Pkt = '2'
  group by del_no
  having count(distinct direction) = 2
),
cte2 as (
  select t.del_no,
         to_char(min(start_datetimestamp), 'YYYY-MM') as _Month, 
         string_agg(distinct env, '/') as Env
  from cte c
  inner join tableName t on c.del_no = t.del_no
  group by t.del_no
)
select _Month, env, count(env) as Counts
from cte2
group by _Month, env
```

- The first cte was used to filter out any **del_no** with incomplete round.
- The second cte was used to obtain Environments combination and start month per **del_no**
- We then aggregate by Month and Environment to get the count.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/GY-3cyeT)

Comment: Hi @SelVazi, sorry about that but the query is giving wrong output in condition -4 IF 'Env' is different. I have added 2 more sample in original data. It's giving 2 separate output for individual 'Env'

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer @SelVazi. It's working now. Cheers

Comment: Glad to hear I could help :)